# Ruby Ohm, undefined method exception when trying create a model setting an array with ids

Tags: ruby, ohm

I have tried to set an array with ids in a model attribute like is explained within https://github.com/soveran/ohm#models but I get an exception. What is wrong in my code?

## Model

```
class Event < Ohm::Model

attribute :title
set :attendees, :User

end
```

## Test

```
@fran = User.create(name: "Fran", email: 'fran@gmail.com')
@jose = User.create(name: "Jose", email: 'jose@hotmail.com')

event = Event.create(title: 'Party in Las Vegas', attendees: [@fran.id,@jose.id])

NoMethodError: undefined method `attendees=' for #<Event:0x000000020fb430>
    /home/ciro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohm-2.0.1/lib/ohm.rb:1470:in `block in update_attributes'
    /home/ciro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohm-2.0.1/lib/ohm.rb:1470:in `each'
    /home/ciro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohm-2.0.1/lib/ohm.rb:1470:in `update_attributes'
```

Comment: you have a typo - once you write `attendes` and once `attendees`

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake in the "copy - paste". Now is fixed in the post. In the model I have "attendees" and in the test too. I have check it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`Set#add`](https://github.com/soveran/ohm/blob/master/lib/ohm.rb#L565) method for this to work and that method only takes 1 argument:

```
@fran = User.create(name: "Fran", email: 'fran@gmail.com')
@jose = User.create(name: "Jose", email: 'jose@hotmail.com')

event = Event.create(title: 'Party in Las Vegas')
event.attendees.add(@fran)
event.attendees.add(@jose)
```

If these are meant to be associations then I'd look at [`collections`](https://github.com/soveran/ohm#associations)